# IntelliJ gradle - unknown properties

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, build.gradle

The error:

> Build file 'C:\Users\Me\Dev\project\app\build.gradle' line: 21
>
> - What went wrong:
>     A problem occurred evaluating root project 'app'.
>     Could not get unknown property 'libraries' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

inside app.gradle

```
dependencies{
    compile libraries.my_lib
    deploy libraries.my_lib
}
```

inside project.gradle

```
ext.libraries = {
    my_lib:    'com.myCompany:my-lib:1.0.0'
}
```

inside pom.xml

```
<modules>
    <module>my-lib</modules>
</modules>
```

Pressing CTRL+Space in app.gradle's `libaries.` shows the my_lib library that may be autocompleted, but when compiling using `gradle clean deploy`, it fails and returns the message above.

This only happened after I updated the IDE to the latest IntelliJ.

Comment: Where do you apply `project.gradle`? Did you try to use `project.libraries.my_lib`?

Answer (score 3):

`ext` defines extensions only for a project it was called in. In your case, `libraries.my_lib` is defined in `project.gradle` (I guess, it is `build.gradle` in `project` directory) and, thus, is not available in a different build file (`app.gradle`, which is again, I guess, is a `build.gradle` in `app` directory)) unless `project` is not a *parent* of `app`. Child projects have access to parent's properties, and that is the only way to share `ext`: projects should be related to each other.

BTW, you can define properties in `gradle.properties` file. There may be many of them, one for every project in your build. Placing one `gradle.properties` in the root of your build you apply its content to the root of your project tree, thus, making the properties available everywhere (the same applies to `ext` block of a root object, as it follows from the previous paragraph).